# How to export a private report in an interactive report and import to another app (preserving state)

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

We want to export a users private report in an interactive report in one app in a workspace to another app in the same workspace having the same interactive report. Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

A blog by Yvonne explains one way to do this [here](https://yvonnebakx.wordpress.com/2020/12/24/oracle-apex-ir-old-reports/)

Another way is to export the app and include the private reports. Then copy/paste the  flow api calls concerning the private reports from the export PL/SQL file, to another export file wherever needed (be careful though).